# Pygame class menu

Tags: python, class, button, pygame

I thought I would give pygame a try and have ran into an issue that I hope someone can help me with. I would like to have a class def to create the quit button but when I do this I can't get the mouse collision. I am most likely doing it wrong, but would really appreciate the help.

It works in the state I have below but not when I put it in a def!

```
pygame.init()


class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.screen = (pygame.display.set_mode((self.screen_width, self.screen_height)))
        self.FPS = 30
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        self.menu_open = True
        self.colors = {"red": (255, 0, 0),
                       "green": (0, 255, 0),
                       "blue": (0, 0, 255),
                       "white": (255, 255, 255),
                       "black": (0, 0, 0),
                       "brown": (153, 76, 0),
                       "grey": (100, 100, 100)}

    def setup(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.colors["black"])
        pygame.display.set_caption("Menu Test!")

    def text(self, message, text_color, x_pos, y_pos):
        text = self.font.render(message, True, (self.colors[text_color]))
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(x_pos, y_pos))
        self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)

    def exit(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.colors["black"])
        text = self.font.render("Thank you for playing. Goodbye!", True,
                                (self.colors["white"]))
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(self.screen_width / 2,
                                          self.screen_height / 2))
        self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        sleep(3)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


def main():
    window = Window()
    window.setup()
```

This is the bit i would like in a class def

```
    quit_button = pygame.draw.rect(window.screen, window.colors["white"],
                                   (window.screen_width / 2 - 100,
                                    window.screen_height / 1.5 - 25, 200, 50), 0)
    window.text("QUIT", "red", window.screen_width / 2, window.screen_height / 1.5)
    pygame.display.update()

    while window.menu_open == 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

And this is where it get the posistion of the mouse click on the rect.

```
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if quit_button.collidepoint(pos):
                    window.exit()
                else:
                    print("Error Line 48")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class (in this case I use a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` subclass) with an `image` and a `rect` attribute and blit the text onto the image.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


pg.init()

class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.FPS = 30
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.font = pg.font.SysFont("Arial", 25)
        self.menu_open = True
        self.colors = {"red": (255, 0, 0),
                       "green": (0, 255, 0),
                       "blue": (0, 0, 255),
                       "white": (255, 255, 255),
                       "black": (0, 0, 0),
                       "brown": (153, 76, 0),
                       "grey": (100, 100, 100)}

    def setup(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.colors["black"])
        pg.display.set_caption("Menu Test!")

    def text(self, message, text_color, x_pos, y_pos):
        text = self.font.render(message, True, (self.colors[text_color]))
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(x_pos, y_pos))
        self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)

    def exit(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.colors["black"])
        text = self.font.render("Thank you for playing. Goodbye!", True,
                                (self.colors["white"]))
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(self.rect.w/2, self.rect.h/2))
        self.screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        pg.display.update()
        pg.time.wait(1000)
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()


class Button(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, text, window):
        super().__init__()  # Call __init__ of the parent class.
        # Render the text.
        self.text_surf = window.font.render(text, True, window.colors["black"])
        self.image = pg.Surface((self.text_surf.get_width()+40,
                                 self.text_surf.get_height()+20))
        self.image.fill(window.colors["white"])
        # Now blit the text onto the self.image.
        self.image.blit(self.text_surf, (20, 10))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)


def main():
    window = Window()
    window.setup()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    # gui is a sprite group which will contain the button sprites.
    gui = pg.sprite.Group()
    # Instantiate some buttons.
    quit_button = Button(
        pos=(window.rect.w/2 - 100, window.rect.h/1.5 - 25),
        text="QUIT",
        window=window,
        )
    hello_button = Button(
        pos=(window.rect.w/8, window.rect.h/2),
        text="hello",
        window=window,
        )
    # Add the buttons to the gui group.
    gui.add(quit_button, hello_button)

    while window.menu_open == True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                window.exit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                # Handle button events.
                if quit_button.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    window.exit()
                elif hello_button.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    print("hello")

        gui.update()  # Call update methods of contained sprites.
        gui.draw(window.screen)  # Draw all sprites.
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

A bit more advanced solution would be to handle the events in the `Button` class and then call a callback function which you have to pass during the instantiation.

```
class Button(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, text, window, callback):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_surf = window.font.render(text, True, window.colors["black"])
        self.image = pg.Surface((self.text_surf.get_width()+40,
                                 self.text_surf.get_height()+20))
        self.image.fill(window.colors["white"])
        self.image.blit(self.text_surf, (20, 10))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        # The callback function will be called when
        # the left mouse button gets pressed.
        self.callback = callback

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.callback()  # Call the callback function.


def main():
    window = Window()
    window.setup()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    gui = pg.sprite.Group()
    quit_button = Button(
        pos=(window.rect.w/2 - 100, window.rect.h/1.5 - 25),
        text="QUIT",
        window=window,
        callback=window.exit,  # Pass the callback function.
        )
    hello_button = Button(
        pos=(window.rect.w/8, window.rect.h/2),
        text="hello",
        window=window,
        callback=lambda: print("hello"),  # Pass the callback function.
        )
    gui.add(quit_button, hello_button)

    while window.menu_open == True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                window.exit()
            # Iterate over the gui group and pass the event to the buttons.
            # If they collide with the mouse, call the callback func.
            for button in gui:
                button.handle_event(event)

        gui.update()
        gui.draw(window.screen)
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you need a class, pygame sprite and sprite group tutorial check out [Program Arcade Games' chapter 12 and 13](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13).